# Customer can't login or register

Tags: magento-1.9, login, register, magento1.9.3

I have some issue, customers can't `login` or `create` account and redirects to login-register page !

The `form key` is well present in all `login.phtml` files.

Comment: Have you some error in logs ?

Comment: `exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message'Invalid block type: Mage_Scrollingcart_Block_Index' in /home/dimitrisgalanis/public_html/app/Mage.php:595`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt for two things :

1. **Cookies**:

   Check this config : `Admin > System > Configuration > General > Web > Session Cookie Management` then set this:

   - Cookie path : `/`
   - Cookie domaine : `domaine.com`
2. **Formkey**

   Check in your current theme if `login.phtml` has well the `formkey`

   Paths:

   - `app/design/frontend/{yourPackage}/{yourTheme}/template/customer/form/login.phtml`
   - `app/design/frontend/{yourPackage}/{yourTheme}/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml`

   formkey :

   - `<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>`
   - `<div><input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" /></div>`

Comment: Yes all these are set as you say

Comment: In Cookie domaine I had ".domaine.com"
I deleted the "." and now it works like a charm

Comment: Good ! good luck